# how to cover ios' baterry&time bar under my AIR app

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I use flash builder to develop a game bases on AIR, but here are the question: my app's top position covered by ios' battery&time bar, so I cant click those buttons on the top position. How to resolve this question by using AS3.0 or some other methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the Device's notification bar at compile time by setting `<fullScreen>true</fullScreen>` in your `myApp-app.xml` [descriptor file](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-7fe4), you cannot control this at run time though.

Comment: On devices running iOS 7 this doesn't work anymore, as status bar is overlayed, AFAIK. I "solved" this using css to add some padding on the top of the ActionBar skin when iOS is detected.

Comment: Hmm, wasn't aware of that issue :/ is that an OS thing where the overlay can't be hidden, or is it that AIR Mobile can't currently control it?

Comment: As I read [this](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5712234) adobe forum thread it's a OS kinda thing. At the bottom of this page you can find the suggested padding and how to implement it in the css.